# Can rotating a polygon 180 degree produce its reflection?

Tags: reflection, graphics, rotation, computer-vision

I have written code for Reflection in Java in the traditional way , I know how to make reflection of a Polygon.

My question is about trying something new, I was thinking If I rotate a polygon at 180 degrees will it produce the reflection of the polygon?? I think it will produce its reflection but will it be mathematically acceptable??

Comment: This is a geometry question with no relation to Java!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the shape. Some polygons have rotational symmetry, some have reflectional symmetry. If you rotate a rectangle by 180 degrees, or reflect it in a suitable axis, you get back the same shape.

But generally, no. They are different operations. If you rotate a shape by 180 degrees, you get an upside down shape, not a reflected shape.

Comment: hmmm, So Circle has rotational symmetry and square has reflectional symmetry

Comment: @Taimour A circle and a square both have rotational symmetry _and_ reflectional symmetry. But a circle has more of both kinds.

Comment: Why circle has more of both kind?

Comment: There are four axes of symmetry for a square: four lines you could place a mirror across and see an identical square. For a circle, _any_ line going through the centre is an axis of symmetry. Similarly, if you rotate a square through 90, 180 or 270 degrees you get an identical square. But if you rotate a circle through _any_ angle, you get an identical circle. A circle is much more symmetrical than a square.

Answer (score 4):

Think of a triangle with a 90°angle:

```
|\
|_\
```

Apply a 180° rotation:

```
 _
\ |
 \|
```

That's not the reflection of the triangle

On some shape like squares or rectangles it will work but usually it won't.